# 8 - How to override the DatabaQueue from module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have to override the default implementation of the `DatabaseQueue` in Drupal 8. The reasons for this are not important.

I was looking at the `QueueFactory` and I learnt that for each queue *worker* there can be a different `QueueInterface` implementation. If it's not specified they fall back to the `DatabaseQueue` (well in fact one can specify different queue *factory* but this simplification is quite accurate anyway).

The `QueueFactory` uses the `Settings` object as it's source of configuration for the queues:

```php
$this->settings->get('queue_service_' . $name, $this->settings->get('queue_default', 'queue.database'));
```

The problem is (as far as I can tell) that `Settings` object takes configuration data from the `sites/*/settings.php` file. In fact, if I extend this file with queue configuration, like this one:

```php
$settings['queue_service_my_custom_queue_worker'] = 'my_module.my_custom_queue_factory';
```

then it works fine.

But here's the deal. I'm creating a module that will be distributed to many clients. This approach for editing the `settings.php` file is not ideal. Imagine asking everyone to make this change. It's very prone to errors. So, is there a way to extend those settings from my module?

I tried using the [configuration overrides](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system#providing-overrides-from-modules) but it doesn't work for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decorate the `queue` service to provide a custom behavior of its `get()` method for your custom queue.

See this doc: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-symfony-service

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed!